# loading a nib file that is instantiated from a storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I am pretty new to this story board concept. I have a view nibs dropped in to the storyboard and each corresponding to a UIViewController subclass I have, I tried loading the nib file using the following code:

```
TestViewController *vc = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.profilePicture_.frameHeight + self.profilePicture_.frameY + 10, self.scrollView_.frameWidth, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/aditya15417/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/64E6CEC9-E6DC-4AF5-BF16-11BFB6415BDC/Pulse.app> (loaded)' with name 'TestViewController''
```

So the question is, if I have my nib in the story board is it not possible to use the initWithNibName? If there is a way, how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"some identifier you set in IB"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the instance Class (Programatically)?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading PNRNewsfeedViewController as TestViewController? Is TestViewController the base class for PNRNewsfeedViewController? Make sure that in the nib, the File's Owner custom class is set to PNRNewsfeedViewController, and then allocate a news feed view controller:

```
PNRNewsfeedViewController *vc = [[PNRNewsfeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PNRNewsfeedViewController" bundle:nil];
// ...
```

Comment: sorry.. yea.. that was just a typo.. so I used TestViewController actually

Answer (score 0):

When you use a storyboard, you don't use individual nibs directly, and you don't instantiate view controllers yourself. You can use the `UIStoryboard` class to instantiate a view controller from the storyboard [as described in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW5).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```